# Class structure to formatted JSON in Dart

Tags: json, dart

I've got some classes in Dart and I'd like to get a formatted JSON representation of them.

For example, I've got these classes:

```
class A {
  String a1;
  num a2;
  List<B> bs;
}

class B {
  String b1;
  num b2;
}
```

A formatted JSON of an A-object should look like this:

```
{
  "a1": "value",
  "a2": 42,
  "bs": [
    {
      "b1": "any value",
      "b2": 13
    },
    {
      "b1": "another value",
      "b2": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I looked at some packages in the pub repository, but couldn't find one, that fits my needs. Maybe I missed the right one.

Comment: What packages did you try and what didn't fit?

Comment: I tried [exportable](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/exportable), [jsonx](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/jsonx) and [dson](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dson). I couldn't figure out, how to pass a indent parameter to their encode functionanlity. In the meantime, I changed the jsonx package (added indent to private encoder variable), but that shouldn't be necessary. I'll contact the  author, if there is no way without this change yet.

Answer (score 6):

If these classed do the serialization and deserialization but just don't format the JSON properly you can take the JSON and decode/encode using the `dart:convert` package and pass an indent string.

see https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-convert.JsonEncoder#id_JsonEncoder-withIndent

```dart
import 'dart:convert' show JSON, JsonEncoder;

...

String json = jsonFromSerializationLib();

print(new JsonEncoder.withIndent('  ').convert(JSON.decode(j)));
```

Comment: I guess you need formatting only to present the output to the user (printing or writing to a file). I think there are other things involved then that cause more delay. The 'indent' was introduced just a few weeks ago. I guess the serialization frameworks will add support for it at some time (especially when you create a feature request).

Comment: That's right. I didn't know, that 'indent' was only recently introduced. I'll create a feature request.